# Verify detached xml signature using public key

Tags: digital-signature, pki, xml-signature

I want to verify detached XML signature using a public key.

I have tried using gpg and openssl but no success.
Can anyone provide me with steps to verify using a public key.

Comment: Was the XML signature made according to XMLDSig or PKCS#7 or  ... ? What language / OS / development tool do you need the solution for?

Comment: Yes..it was made according to XMLDSig. I created my public key and  ran command "openssl dgst -verify pubkey.pem -signature
abcd.gz.sig abcd.gz""" but Verification failure was the result. So, is there are tool through which we can verify this pure XML detached signature. Please let me know if you require more information. Thanks.